# I want to use cv2_imshow in colab

Tags: opencv, google-colaboratory

```html
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model



img_color = cv.imread('test3.jpg', cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
img_gray = cv.cvtColor(img_color, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


ret,img_binary = cv.threshold(img_gray, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv.THRESH_OTSU)

kernel = cv.getStructuringElement( cv.MORPH_RECT, ( 5, 5 ) )
img_binary = cv.morphologyEx(img_binary, cv. MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

cv2_imshow('digit', img_binary)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

This is the process of training a model in handwritten and testing the trained model.
I want to load an image using imshow() in colab.

Is there any way to use it without setting the file path?

Comment: *I want to load an image using imshow() in colab*. You can't load an image using `imshow()`. Please rephrase your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [matplotlib's function](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) for it

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(18, 10)
plt.axis("off")
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [20, 10]
plt.imshow(img_binary)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Surely that won’t work unless you `import` something?

Comment: @MarkSetchell of course!